# Gmaps.js Route with multiple markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, routes, gmaps.js

I am trying to build something similar to [this example](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/travel_route.html).

The example's workflow is the following:

1. add 2 markers to map.
2. click "get route"
3. keep clicking forward until you get from point A to point B

If a user inserts a third marker -> click get route etc, original route gets redrawn.

What I want to achieve is the following. I have a fixed destination, and user inserts one marker, clicks get_route, then forward until route gets drawn, one step at a time. So far so good.
I have made it possible for the user to add a second marker, click get route, and see the route drawn to the destination.

The problem I am facing is the following. On the second marker, the first time the user clicks forward, he gets two steps at once drawn, after that another two, etc. The third marker, 3steps per click. 4th marker, 4 steps per click, etc. 
Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#forward').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $('#back').attr('disabled', 'disabled');    
  $('#get_route').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    count = 0;
    map.getRoutes({
      origin: [map.markers[map.markers.length-1].getPosition().lat(), map.markers[map.markers.length-1].getPosition().lng()],
      destination: [meetinglat, meetinglng],
      travelMode : google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING,
      callback: function(e){
        route = new GMaps.Route({
          map: map,
          route: e[e.length-1], // e[0] initially
          strokeColor: '#336699',
          strokeOpacity: 0.5,
          strokeWeight: 10,
          destination: [meetinglat, meetinglng]
        });         
        $('#forward').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#back').removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
    $('#forward').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      route.forward();

      if(route.step_count <= route.steps_length && count < route.steps_length){
        count++;
        $('#steps').append('<li>'+route.step_count+' '+route.steps[route.step_count-1].instructions+'</li>');
        $("#container").scrollTop($("#container")[0].scrollHeight);
      }
    });
    $('#back').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      route.back();

      if(route.step_count >= 0){
        $('#steps').find('li').last().remove();
        count--;
        }
    });
  });

  map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: meetinglat,
    lng: meetinglng,
    zoom: 17,
    height: '500px',
    click: function(e){
      map.addMarker({
        lat: e.latLng.lat(),
        lng: e.latLng.lng()
      });
    }
  });
```

Can you tell if I am missing something here? When a new route gets created, I am passing the correct one obviously, as it is the one that gets drawn.

The problem is on the first time the user clicks "forward" after inserting the second marker, because the 2 steps run at once. The third time, 3 steps, 4th time 4 steps, etc.

Thanks very much

Edit: [jsBin](http://output.jsbin.com/fobetu/1/)

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: edited original post

Comment: The only thing I can see that might be causing problems is your counter. Make sure to reset it each time you draw a new path.

Comment: I reset it every time the "Get Route" button is clicked.
I don't think the counter does anything to do with the problem that I am facing, because if we completely remove it, we can observe the same behaviour. I've come to think that I might have to tweak something in the original gmaps.js code, I'll post here when I find out

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the issue.

It seems that "forward" and "back" click events were bubbling-propagation, so that was the reason for the behaviour it had. (1 step per click 1st marker, 2 step per click 2nd marker, 3 step per click 3rd marker etc).

I added:

```
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

at the end of both forward and back click event handlers. Working as expected now